# How to limit the number of fields to be returned and apply the array slice in nested array in a single operation in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have mongodb documents like this:

```
    [{ "_id" : 5, "type" : "food", "item" : "aaa", "ratings" : [ 5, 8, 9 ] },
    { "_id" : 7, "type" : "food", "item" : "bbb", "ratings" : [ 9, 8, 7 ] }]
```

I want to get only the field "rating" with its elements to be limited using $slice. 
I am able to apply both of the operation individually like as given below:

a) for getting only rating field:

```
>db.test.find( { _id: 5 }, { ratings: 1} )
{ "_id" : 5, "ratings" : [ 5, 8, 9 ] }
```

b) for slicing the number of sub-records in rating array:

```
 >db.test.find( { _id: 5 }, { ratings: { $slice: 2 } } )
 { "_id" : 5, "type" : "food", "item" : "aaa", "ratings" : [ 5, 8 ] }
```

My desired result is :

```
{ "_id" : 5, "ratings" : [ 5, 8] }
```

How to combine these two operations in an efficient way in a single query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the docs [**Limit Fields to Return from a Query**](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)?

Comment: @chirdam Yes, by reading that only i could be able to perform the operations mentioned in the a) to limit the field to be returned and b) to slice the array elements in my question. But I could not perform the operation which combines the tasks of a) and b)

Comment: That would be `db.test.find( { _id: 5 }, { type: 0, item: 0, ratings: { $slice: 2 } } )`

Comment: Thanks alot, It worked. Can you please explain it?

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways.

1. use agrregate with $project and $slice.
2. As shown by Chridam. in a find command you can tell which field you want to show.

when you do `db.test.find({_id:5}) it is like -> select * from test where _id = 5`.

but when you do `db.test.find({_id:5},{type:0, item:0}) that make it selective on columns you want to view -> select ratings from test where _id = 5`.

`type:0 and item:0` means you are not interested in fetching these fields.